# Deserialize JSON to LINQ object

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, linq, visual-studio-2008, json

In VB.Net class, I have a JSON data as string. I want to convert them to LINQ class Object.

`

```
'definition
    Dim js As New System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer  

'return the data
    Dim rawdata = js.DeserializeObject(strVal)

' i have this object , generated by LINQ
dim oCustomForm= new CustomForm

'what i need is to Deserialize the string INTO that object

'i tried this....but :(

        'Dim oCustomForm As List(Of CustomForm) = CType(rawdata, List(Of CustomForm))
        'Dim oCustomForm As new CustomForm = rawdata
`
```

Thanks....

Comment: the result form deserialize is   *System.Collections.Generic.List*  -> i want to convert it to *oCustomForm* ..which is an object form *CustomForms* class----

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the [Json.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/) library? I'm using it for serializing/deserializing objects to/from JSON and works perfectly.

It's much better than the built-in .NET serialization because it doesn't save the assembly-related data (which can make a deserialization a real trouble).

HTH

Answer (score 0):

[How to: Serialize and Deserialize JSON Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412179.aspx)

Comment: it Gave me .... Expecting element 'root' from namespace ''.. Encountered 'None'  with name '', namespace ''.